# In a world where gravity pass from 1 G to 5 G in a cycle of 365 days, can planes fly all the time?

Tags: physics, earth-like, gravity, habitability, airships

I am writing a book and I have this cenario. There is a planet where gravity pass from 1 G to 5 G in a cycle of 365 days. I know that humans can survive till 3-5G, but what about airplanes capability to fly?
Consider the planet an EXACT copy of the Earth in all, except for a "magical" alteration of the gravity.

Comment: It won't be an exact copy, because this is going to have a pretty significant effect on vegetation, wildlife and landscape.

Comment: Also, note that this provides a perpetual motion machine, whereby you can lift up a heavy object in low-G season, and get back more energy from its descent in high-G season than you expended to lift it....

Comment: I think you would also get a heating effect as the gravity increases and a chilling effect as it reduces, since it would be respectively compressing/decompressing the atmosphere on each leg of the cycle. I don't know the math - maybe it would turn out to be unnoticeable, maybe life-ending? Someone with a higher pay grade than me would have to look into it.

Comment: Major frame challenge: that 3-5g number is for human pilots, in a specially designed seat, for a relatively short amount of time. There is absolutely no research to show that surviving even 2g for *days* is plausible, much less 3-5g for weeks. Imagine trying to live life with two adults your exact proportions sitting on top of you at all times.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yes, in Real Life it would be a perpetual motion machine, but on Alessar's imaginary world, it's allowed to happen. (Don't let Real Life stop you, Alessar, this is a good question and it sounds like a fun story.)

Comment: @DanielB Read the comment immediately above this one. Jeez, we have trouble not being physics-lite.

Comment: @JBH If I thought OP was deliberately setting up an alternate world where humans can survive 3-5g, I’d accept it as physics lite, but they seem to be regurgitating a misunderstood factoid from Wikipedia, and I’d rather they be aware that it’s inaccurate

Comment: @DanielB I'd ask "why?" but I don't want to start a debate or a discussion. Frankly, if the education isn't going to materially improve the question (which I don't believe in this case), then it's the right thing to do to not worry about the education. Or, if you just can't stand it, to word it in a way that is supportive of the worldbuilding effort. My problem was using the phrase "frame challenge" without proposing an alternative that supports the worldbuilding effort. (And this is coming from someone who, on a bad day, can be really nasty... and has paid the price for it.)

Comment: @Alessar  I have added a lot to my answer on January 5 to 6.  And you might possibly find some of the additions useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer.

Part One of the long answer discusses how humans could cope with the changing gravity, suggesting they might need help from high gravity aliens or robots when the gravity is at its highest.

Part Two discusses a planet with different gravity in different places.

Part Three discusses the only way I could imagine a planet to naturally have different surface gravity at different times.  And it discusses a lot of problems with such a situation.

Part Four discusses using gravity generators to change the planet's gravity, even though gravity generation is not considered possible.

Part Five discusses using literal magic to generate changing gravity.

and Part six discusses setting the story in a rotating cylindrical space habitat with simulated gravity from centrifugal force, which is by far the most plausible setting.

Long Answer.

Part One: How much surface gravity can humans survive?

Stephen H. Dole, in *Habitable Planets for Man* (1964) discussed that.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

On pages 11 to 13 he discussed the limits of higher gravity which humans can tolerate for long periods of time.

Tests in centrifuges showed that the time a seated person could spend in higher gravity before blacking out for lack of oxygen in the brain decreased as the gravity level increased, and gravity as low as 3 *g* could be tolerated for as much as an hour, while 5 *g* could be tolerated for about 2 minutes.

And other sources say that the longest time subjects have spent in high gravity centrifuges is one week at 1.5 *g*.  Someone could be daring and guess that they could have spent one month, one year, one decade, or the rest of their natural lives in 1.5 *g* without serious side effects.  That would be a rather bold speculation.  And claiming that humans could spend their entire lives in 5 *g* would be an extremely more bold speculation.

So if you want humans visiting and living on the planet when the gravity gets up to even 2 *g*, let alone 5 *g*, you should have them wear antigravity belts and have buildings with antigravity generators and even vehicles with antigravity.  And those antigravity vehicles could "fly", or at least travel through the atmosphere above the ground, using antigravity.  Which would make travel very differently from airplanes on Earth.

Antigravity, or controlled and generated gravity is considered to be highly improbable according to modern physics. if you want your story be somewhat hard on the sliding scale of science fiction hardness you have have to go without antigravity, and the flying vehicles will be much more like Earth  airplanes.  If a low score on the scale is all right for you, antigravity can be used.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/SlidingScale/MohsScaleOfScienceFictionHardness

Without antigravity humans would have sit or lie down, possibly in liquids, during periods of high gravity.  And it would be bad for their health as well as for doing everyday activities, if the periods of high gravity lasted long.

If there are intelligent aliens on the planet adapted to even the highest gravity levels, they ha may have to take care of the humans visiting or living there during the high gravity periods.

The largest arthropod living on land and experiencing one gravity on Earth was a genus of giant millipede.

> Arthropleura (Greek for 'jointed ribs') is a genus of extinct millipede arthropods that lived in what is now North America and Europe around 345 to 290 million years ago,[1](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/SlidingScale/MohsScaleOfScienceFictionHardness) from the Viséan stage of the lower Carboniferous Period to the Sakmarian stage of the lower Permian Period.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropleura) The species of the genus are the largest known land invertebrates of all time, and would have had few, if any, predators.
>
> A. armata grew to be 2.5 metres (8 ft 2 in) long.[4](https://in-the-sky.org/article.php?term=synodic_period) Tracks from Arthropleura up to 50 centimetres (20 in) wide have been found at Joggins, Nova Scotia.[5](https://planetplanet.net/about/) In 2021 a fossil was reported, probably a shed exoskeleton (exuviae) of an Arthropleura with an estimated width of 55 centimetres (22 in), length of 1.9 metres (6 ft 3 in) to 2.63 metres (8 ft 8 in) and body mass of 50 kg (110 lb).[2](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/SlidingScale/MohsScaleOfScienceFictionHardness) Arthropleura was able to grow larger than modern arthropods, partly because of the greater partial pressure of oxygen in Earth's atmosphere at that time and partly because of the lack of large terrestrial vertebrate predators.[6](https://philip-p-ide.uk/doku.php/blog/articles/software/surface_gravity_calc)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropleura

The body mass of *Arthropleura* was large enough to support a brain large enough for intelligence. So if an arthropod with an exoskeleton could reach that size on land on Earth with one *g* surface gravity, a being with the same size, shape, and number of limbs, but with a a vertebrate body structure, should be able to function well on a world with 5*g* surface gravity or higher.  It is possible that far fewer limbs would be necessary, perhaps one pair of arms, or an elephant like trunk, plus two or three pairs of legs for support, sort of like a centaur.

Or the humans could have robots to support them during the high gravity periods.

Part two:  Planet with Variable Gravity.

I find it very difficult to believe in a planet which changes the surface gravity at the same spot on its surface over the course of time and back again.  Of course if gravity control is possible in your fictional universe, there could be giant artificial gravity generators on the planet left by a highly advanced civilization which periodically change the strength of the planet's surface gravity for some reason known to the advanced civilization but not to the characters in the story.

A very fast rotating planet would have a rather oval cross section and would have somewhat higher surface gravity at the poles than at the equator.  There is a limit to such gravity differences because a planet will start to break up if it
rotates too fast.

Part Three:  Interaction with another planet.

So one idea to have the surface gravity of the planet change over time would be to have the planet periodically pass near another planet, close enough for the gravity of the other planet to lessen the gravity on the near side of the planet and increase it on the far side.

I call your planet Vargy, for Variable Gravity.  Vargy orbits its star in a slightly elliptical orbit and experiences no affects on its surface gravity from the star, because it is in free fall around the star, and so experiences only microgravity as on a space station orbiting the Earth.

But if Vargy periodically passes close to another planet orbiting that star, the other planet's gravity much decrease Vargy's surface gravity on the side near to the other planet, and increase  it on the side away from the other planet.

So if Vargy has a surface gravity of 3 *g*, and if when the planets are closest the gravity of the other planet has a strength of 2 *g* at the distance of Vargy, it will reduce the surface gravity of Vargy on the near side to 1 *g* and increase it to 5 *g* on the far side of Vargy.

And at the places on Vargy's surface which are at right angles to the direction to the other planet the 2 *g* pull of the other planet will be horizontal and at right angles to the 3 *g* pull of Vargy. That ought to make conditions on the surface and flying conditions interesting.

And if the planet Vargy rotates several times during the near passage of the other planet, every spot on it surface will experience a change in the total gravity from 1 *g* to 5 *g* during each day of the close encounter, and well as changes in the direction of the gravitational force from straight down to almost sideways.

So the close passages of the other planet would be interesting for those on the ground and for flying air craft.

On the other hand, possibly Vargy is tidally locked to its star, with one side always facing toward the star in eternal day and the other side always facing away from the star in eternal night.  So when the other planet passes closest to Vargy it will be passing either on the sunward side of Vargy or the dark side of Vargy.

Then Vargy might have a surface gravity of 4 *g* and the other planet could have a gravitational force in the close passage of 4 *g*.  That would raise the surface gravity on the side of Vargy away from the other planet to 9 *g* and lower it on the side facing the planet to 1 *g* during the the close encounter.

IN the rest of my discussion of Vargy I will go with it having a surface gravity of 3 *g* and the other planet having a gravitational attraction of 2 *g* at the distance of close encounter.

If I remember correctly, if Vargy has a surface gravity of 3 *g* at a distance of 1 Vargy radius from it's center, it will have a gravitational force equal to 1.5 *g* at a distance of 2 Vargy radii from its centers, and a gravitational force equal to 0.75 *g* at distance of 4 Vargy radii from its center, and so on.

So if the other planet was a twin of Vargy, with the same mass and radius and thus withthe sme surface gravity of 3 *g*, it would have to be less than i Vargy radius from Vargy at the closest approach, and at such a short distances its gravitational attraction  on Varrgy would vary a lot on the different parts of Vargy's surface instead of being uniformly 2 *g*.

Thus the other planet should be more massive than Vargy and have a much greater radius than Vargy to have a gravitational attraction equal to 2*g* while passing Vargy at great enough distance that its gravity doesn't vary noticeably across the diameter of Vargy.

If the other planet has a surface gravity of 4 *g*, it would have a gravitational attraction equal to 2 *g* at a distance of of 2 radii from  its center.

If the other planet has a surface gravity of 8 *g*, it would have a gravitational attraction equal to 4 *g* at a distance of of 2 radii from  its center, and a gravitational attraction equal to 2 *g* at a distance of of 4 radii from  its center.

If the other planet has a surface gravity of 16 *g*, it would have a gravitational attraction equal to 8 *g* at a distance of of 2 radii from  its center, and a gravitational attraction equal to 4 *g* at a distance of of 4 radii from its center, and a gravitational attraction equal to 2 *g* at a distance of of 8 radii from  its center.

How high can the surface gravity of a planet get?

The more massive and dense a rocky planet is the higher its surface gravity can get.  But the more massive a rocky planet is, the more gaseous elements its gravity will attract and capture, including the ultra light hydrogen and helium.  Thus the most massive rocky planets will probably become the cores of giant planets.  Unless various factors prevent them from gaining large amounts of hydrogen and helium.

And the giant planets in our solar systems have comparatively low surface gravities - or cloud top gravities since they don't have solid surfaces.

The "surface" gravity at cloud top layer of Uranus is 0.886 *g*, that of Saturn 1.065 *g*, that of Neptune 1.137 *g*, and that of Jupiter 2.528 *g*.

Jupiter has a mean radius of 69,911 kilometers.  So if the other planet had the same mass and radius as Jupiter, Vargy would have to pass a lot less than 2 Jupiter radii from the center that planet, and a lot less than 69,911 kilometers from its surface.

Fortunately planets more massive than Jupiter don't get much larger than Jupiter.  With greater and greater mass, their gravity compresses their materials more and more, and they become more dense.

When planets reach a radius of about 1.15 that of Jupiter, about 80,397 kilometers, they stop growing in radius.  If more mass is added they become more dense instead of growing in radius.  If enough mass is added they actually shrink in radius and become smaller and and smaller as more mass is added.

The most massive planets can have a mass of about 13 Jupiter masses or about 4,131.4 Earth masses.  More massive objects are called brown dwarfs until they reach about 75 times the mass of Jupiter or 23,835 times the mass of Earth and become very low mass stars, and they also have radii similar to that of Jupiter.

According to an online surface gravity calculator:

https://philip-p-ide.uk/doku.php/blog/articles/software/surface_gravity_calc

A planet with 13 times the mass of Jupiter would have a surface gravity of 28 *g* with a radius of 80,397 kilometers and a surface gravity of 34.38 *g* with a radius of 69,911 kilometers.  A brown dwarf with a mass of 75 Jupiters or 23,835 Earths, would have a surface gravity of 149.99 *g* with a radius of 80,397 kilometers and a surface gravity of 198.35 *g* with a radius of 69,911 kilometers.

So it is possible for the other planet (or brown dwarf) to have a sufficiently high surface gravity and planetary radius that Vargy can pass it at a relatively safe distance ofhundreds of thousands of kilometers, maybe millions of kilometers, and still experience 2 *g* equivalent gravitational force at that close passage.

But there are problems with marking the other planet too massive.

Planets can not have orbits around their stars too close.  Planets have forbidden zones around them which eject other objects out of orbit.  I don't know how to calculate the forbidden zone of a planet, but it depends on the mass of the planet, the mass of the star, and the distance between them.
There is a a large range in the possible mass ranges of planets, and of stars, and of the the distances of planetary orbits around stars.  Thus there is a vast range in the possible forbidden zones of planets.
But the other planet in this case has to be at least several times as massive as Vargy (which in turn should be several times as massive as Earth) and so should have a rather large forbidden zone.

And since Vargy is probably supposed to be a habitable planet, instead of being as hot as mercury or as cold as Neptune, it probably has to have a surface temperature similar to Earth and receive about as much radiation from its star as Earth gets from the Sun. So the dimmer the star is compared to the Sun, the closer Vargy will have to orbit to it to receive as much radiation as Earth gets from the Sun, and the shorter its orbital period will be. And the more luminous the star is compared to the Sun, the farther Vargy will have to orbit from it to receive as much radiation as Earth gets from the Sun, and the longer its orbital period will be.

But there are limits to the mass and luminosity of stars capable of having naturally occurring human habitable planets with the right temperatures and with oxygen rich atmospheres.  And thus there are limits to the orbital parameters of Vargy if it is supposed to be human habitable.

And the other planet has to have an orbit similar to that of Vargy, if it sometimes passes close to Vargy, and that puts limits on the orbital parameters and the forbidden zone of the other planet.   So it might not be possible for the two planets to pass close enough for the other planet to change the surface gravity of Vargy noticeably.

It is possible that an advanced civilization terraformed Vargy some time the past, and that it is habitable despite orbiting a star that is not suitable for having naturally habitable planets.  That could help with the orbit of Vargy, and thus of the other planet, possibly making it possible for Vargy and the other planet to pass close.

The smallest known ratio between the semi-major axis of two planetary orbits in the same system is between Kepler-36 b and Kepler-36 c.

Planet b has a semi-major axis of 0.1153 Astronomical Units (AU) and planet C has a semi-major axis of 0.1283 AU, which is 1.112749 that of b.  The difference is only about 0.013 AU, or about 1,944,772.3 kilometers.  So the two planets can pass that close to each other.

Kepler 36-c has a mass of about 7.13 Earths, and a radius of about 3.679 Earth radius, and so about 23,438.909 kilometers.  It should have a surface gravity of about 0.53 *g*.  Kepler 36-b has a mass of about 3.83 Earths, and a radius of about 1.498 Earth radius, and so about 9,543.7 kilometers.  It should have a surface gravity of about 1.71 *g*.

So they don't have surface gravity as high as 2 *g* and couldn't have a gravitational force as high as 2 *g* at a distance of about 1,944,772.3 kilometers.
Kepler-36 b & C also orbit very close to their star Kepler-36, which is at least as luminous as the sun and should several times as hot as Mercury.

When the other planet and Vargy are closest to each other, they will be more or less lined up with their star, so the inner one will seem to pass in front of the star as seen from the outer one, and the outer one will seem to be opposite to the star as seen from inner one.
The time it takes too planets to return to such a line up is called the synodic period.

This article:

https://in-the-sky.org/article.php?term=synodic_period

Has a graph showing the synodic periods other other planets in our solar system relative to Earth, with curves showing the calculated synodic periods at various distances.  You will note that the synodic periods are shorter for planets with orbital periods more different from that of Earth, and longer for planets with orbital periods closer to to that of Earth.

> Those planets which are closest to the Earth – Venus and Mars – have very long synodic periods. This is because they orbit the Sun at speeds very similar to that of the Earth.

Since the other planet and Vargy pass close to each other, they should have very close orbits and very similar orbital periods, and thus their synodic period should be very long compared to their orbital speeds.

So if it takes about 365 days, about one Earth year, for the two planets to pass close to each other, their orbital periods must be small fractions of an Earth year and they must orbit very close to a star with low mass and low luminosity in order for Vargy to have an Earthlike temperature.

So I think that it is probably impossible to design a system where the masses of the star and the planets and the orbits of the planets are such that Vargy periodically has changes in its experienced surface gravity due to the closeness of the other planet.

Astrophysicist Sean Raymond offers to help in world building, so he might possibly be able to calculate a system for your, or more likely immediately see why such a system would be impossible.

https://planetplanet.net/about/

Part Four:  Planet has gravity Generators.

The question asks for a planet that otherwise is identical to Earth.  Thus it should have a surface gravity of 1 *g*. So artificial gravity generators would be necessary to periodically increase the surface gravity up to 5 *g* and lower it back down to 1 *g* again.

It wouldn't be a good idea to put the gravity generators in the core of the planet Vargy.  They would be crushed by the pressure at the center.  There should be thousands or millions or billions of gravity generators buried a short distance below the surface of the planet, each affecting the gravity strongly over a large but relatively small compared to the planet radius. Thus the added gravity would only affect the rocks down to a relatively short distance and the entire planet.

If the entire planet flexed as the generators increased and decreased the gravity, it would have effects of various kinds, some probably unwelcome like earthquakes.  Having only the upper surface of the planet flex under changing gravity would reduce those effects.

I don't have the faintest idea why an advanced civilization would do this, except as some kind of experiment.  I note that the gravity generations would have to be powered.  So possibly the characters living on on the planet Vargy are part of a society which has to keep the generators fueled.  Or possibly a long ago advanced civilization built the gravity generators and gave them very long lasting fuel supplies.

Part Five: "magical" gravity.

Or maybe the varying surface gravity of Vargy is indeed "magical" and your story is classed as a fantasy, at least as far as that aspect of it is concerned.

Part Six:  An Artificial Space Habitat.

Or you could set you star in an artificial space habitat, a enclosed rotating hollow cylinder with simulated gravity from centrifugal force on the inside of the outer shell.

The strength of the simulated gravity would depend on the radius of the cylinder and the speed of rotation.

And if the habitat contains a concentric series of cylinders one instead the other, their simulated surface gravities will vary.  So the innermost such cylinder might have a one 1 *g* simulated gravity, and the outermost cylinder might have a 5 *g* simulated gravity.

The strength of known building materials puts a limit on the possible radius of such a space habitat, especially if the outermost cylinder has a simulated gravity of 5 *g*, but the length of the cylinder might possibly be tens or hundreds of thousands, possibly millions, of kilometers. Certainly long enough to make airplanes useful for travel.

If the distances between the concentric cylinders are great enough, there will be enough space for aircraft to take off, travel, and land.  I guess a hundred meters might be sufficient if the pilots are very careful not to crash into the ceilings above them.  and aircraft might have to avoid columns between the various "decks". And wind patterns might be odd in bodies or air in the spaces between two rotating cylinders.

And if the inner cylinders have periodical holes large enough for aircraft to pass through, aircraft could fly from one level to another, in varying gravity.

Or maybe the cylinders of different radius and thus different simulated surface gravity would not be one inside the other, but end to end.  The habitat could have a repeating pattern of cylinders of different radius, so that to get to another cylinder with the same radius and surface gravity, an airplane would have to fly over intervening cylinders with different simulated gravity.

Or maybe to get the effect of the simulated gravity changing in the same location over time, there could be just one cylinder with one surface, but the rotation of the cylinder could be speeded up and slowed down to change the simulated surface gravity all over the inner surface.

So the cylinder that people live on the inner surface of could be within another outer cylinder and there could be a lot of very large machinery connected them to move them relative to each other. A force that made the inner cylinder move in one direction make the other cylinder move in the opposite direction.

A lot of energy would be needed to constantly change the rotational speed of the inner cylinder.  There could be countless super giant solar panels collecting solar energy and beaming it to receivers on the outer cylinder to power the motors turning the inner cylinder.

And possibly a system of giant flywheels might store energy during one process and release it in the opposite process, reducing the energy needed.

So here is a scientifically possible, though technologically formidable, way for an artificial world to experience varying surface gravity.

Answer (score 6):

Given that real world airplanes can fly at G loads well above 5 G, I'm going to say "yes", airplanes can continue to fly at 5 G.

Lift produced by a wing is proportional to the square of airspeed, so at 4 G your stall speed would be twice what it is at 1 G, making landing and taking off during the high-G part of the cycle potentially problematic (LONG runways likely required).  The power requirements for hover by rotorcraft are approximately linear with weight (=> G load), so that's not fully ruled out, either.  An imporant factor is the relative disability of unaltered humans at G loads above 3 G; there may be a strong tendency to avoid scheduling departures and arrivals when the gravity is highest -- but it's very definitely possible for aircraft already aloft to remain aloft at 5 G or even higher (aerobatic aircraft can maintain flight at up to 9 or 10 G).

Rocket launches to orbit would also be heavily affected -- I've read that if Earth's gravity due to mass were a mere 25% higher than it is, humans might not have been able to achieve orbit in the ca. 1960 time frame (or ever, if rocket engine development stalled at that level due to lack of applications).

Comment: While I like a checkmark as well as the next person, I might point out that they tend to prevent (some) others from reading and answering the question -- potentially pushing away even better answers than mine.  The general recommendation is to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer, since people around the world may not even be awake when you post a question.

Comment: This 5G military aircraft can endure has to do with 1) taking off with huge thrust and 2) flying tight curves. I think *landing safely* would be a huge problem at 5G, you'd need downward reverse thrust, not only forward reverse thrust. Landing relies on lift capability of the aircraft. With military jets this lifting capability is already small, they need huge runways, or parachute to land. Certain manouvres, like diving down on a target and pulling up can't be done..

Comment: @Goodies  If you can fly a 5G maneuver, you can *in theory* land at 5G.  Your landing speed would be 5^1/2 times what it would be in 1G, however, which would typically require a very long runway and would surely require the aircraft to be designed to take it (SR-71 and X-15 had very high landing speeds, but got it done).  Thrust hover gets harder faster than landing in wing lift, though; you don't need 5x the thrust to generate 5x the lift by going a bit more than twice as fast as your slowest speed.

Comment: You're right about forward speed, theoretical.. but I don't think your square root formula covers the issues with controlling downward speed, while preparing for landing.  When the approach goes well, events will happen 2x as quickly. A human pilot may have issues hitting the touchdown point accurately. So your longer runway won't help. Upward reverse thrust is a solution for all this.